# Need to disable loading resources on login page of XPages application

Tags: xpages

We are in the midst of troubleshooting intermittent 403 errors in our application.  One of the issues that came up was that we are loading resources on our login page. The resources intermittently produce 401 errors in our Integration environment. None of these are needed until after the user has logged into the application.

All of these resources are stored in the NSF, none use a CDN. These resources are loaded via a Theme on every page.

Naturally, I thought the solution was to disable the theme of the login XPage.  I went about setting `disableTheme="true"` on the `<xp:view>` tag.  For some reason this did not work and the resources are still loaded on the page.

Can anyone suggest how to make sure the resources are NOT loaded on this particular page?

[image]

Comment: It seems that the design elements of your jQuery library isn't considering itself as publicly accessible to anonymous. Something I refactored our login page to implement was to use only resources hosted in the _data/domino/html_, _/icons_, etc. paths, so as to always be publicly accessible (to anonymous). I've restructured my themes to pull from the same source as much as possible as well (one-stop shopping, I hope). This avoids, I believe, the fact that the design element has properties for visibility, within the NSF.

Comment: So you are saying that you keep your resources on the server, and have your themes pull from there.  I wouldn't be able to do that here.

Comment: Are the jQuery, etc. files loaded in the NSF as file resources, or in WebContent/?

Comment: They are in the WebContent/js folder and WebContent/css folder.

Comment: I just tried to access an NSF/WebContent/js resource directly, from one of my apps from an incognito session. I get prompted for a login (no anonymous or Default access allowed by ACL). It looks like you'll need a different place to pull those resources from if you need them in your NSF/login.xsp.

Comment: But I don't need them in my login. I simply want to prevent them from being loaded in my login.xsp. My application theme loads these resources, which are used on nearly every page. I just want to get disable  theme to work, or an alternative.

Comment: Fair enough. Have you tried an alternate theme already for login.xsp? I seem to recall having issues just swapping between themes easily a while back and found setting the xsp.theme property in the beforeRenderResponse did the trick.

Comment: No luck with alternative theme but will try loadingRenderResponse. Was just researching if I can conditionally load resources in the theme to exclude that page.

Comment: You can explicitly compute the rendered property for a resource in a theme, based on XPage. You could just set it to rendered computing off if the current page is not login.xsp. [Here's the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044628/how-to-render-or-hide-theme-resources-only-for-one-xsp/14045481#14045481), courtesy of Per Henrik Lausten.

Comment: Eric, that solves my problem.  Please add this as an answer so I can close this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that resources contained within the *WebContent/* path of an NSF are still protected and require login when that NSF's ACL is set to no access for Anonymous. A couple of ways to get around this are:

1. host the resource files from the server's /domino/... path (html, js, lib, icons)
2. load those resources from a CDN
3. use an alternate theme (mixed results, see the comment thread on the OP's question)
4. computing the individual *resource*'s (or *resources*) tag to *render* for all but a login page

As [Per Henrik Lausten answered on another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044628/how-to-render-or-hide-theme-resources-only-for-one-xsp/14045481#14045481), the implementation with the solution #4 would effectively be:

```xml
<resource rendered="#{javascript:view.getPageName() != '/login.xsp'}">
    <content-type>application/x-javascript</content-type>
    <href>js/jquery-1.11.1.min.css</href>
</resource>
```

Answer (score 2):

For reference: there's a 5th method that involves setting $PublicAccess to "1" on the resources in the WebContent folder to mark them as publicly available.

John Dalsgaard has [a blog post about it with example code](http://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/public-access-to-e-g-an-angular-app-in-your-notes-database/).