# How to give public access to files under webcontent in lotus domino

Tags: xpages, acl, lotus-domino, font-awesome

I have a domino application with XPages that i want to be public. So, i set in the ACL the "Default" to Depositor level with read public documents option, so as to make it public.

When i want to use an image resource i go to its properties security tab and i enable the "available to public access users" checkbox.

Now, I want to use font-awesome in my application and i have font-awesome's folder with its subfolders and files under webcontent folder.

How can i make them public? (in a non-public app, font-awesome works normally with font-awesome's folder under webcontent folder)

Comment: See this answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30901454/785061

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I simply created an agent to set the flag. You can get the code *below*. I use it for an Angular app that I have added to the NSF.

HTH
/John

**Edit:**
Code inserted directly here:

```
Option Public
Option DeclareSub Initialize
Const APP_DIR = “app/”
Const FN_PUBLICACCESS = “$PublicAccess”
Const FLAG_TRUE = “1”
Dim sess As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim nc As NotesNoteCollection
Set db = sess.currentDatabase
Set nc = db.CreateNoteCollection(False)
Call nc.SelectAllDesignElements(True)
Call nc.BuildCollection
Dim d1 As Long
Dim d2 As Long
Dim title As String
Dim flagsExt As String
Dim noteid As String
Dim nextid As String
Dim i As Long
Dim doc As NotesDocument
noteid = nc.Getfirstnoteid()
For i = 1 To nc.Count
‘get the next note ID before removing any notes
nextid = nc.GetNextNoteId(noteid)
Set doc = db.GetDocumentByID(noteid)
title = doc.GetItemValue(“$title”)(0)
flagsExt = doc.GetItemValue(“$flagsExt”)(0)
If LCase(flagsExt) = “w” And Left(LCase(title),Len(APP_DIR)) = LCase(APP_DIR) Then
d1 = d1 + 1
If Not doc.Getitemvalue(FN_PUBLICACCESS)(0) = FLAG_TRUE Then
d2 = d2 + 1
Call  doc.replaceItemValue(FN_PUBLICACCESS,FLAG_TRUE)
Call doc.save(True, False)
Print title & ” – set to allow public access read”
End If
End If
noteid = nextid
Next

Print nc.count & ” design elements checked. “ & d1 & ” elements found in ‘” & APP_DIR & “‘ and “ & d2 & ” updated to give public access”

End Sub
```

Comment: I found this simple change really speeds up the agent.  

`Call nc.SelectAllDesignElements(False) ' We only care about the MiscFormatElements/WebContent, so we can ignore everything else.  

   nc.SelectMiscFormatElements = True`

Comment: I can't get the code from the blog. Seems the blog is down. Please share the code

Answer (score 3):

They still get registered as design notes inside the NSF (which is why they're picking up the default visibility), so I think the only real option is to run an agent to update their visibility, explicitly. Sven Hasselbach has blogged about [this topic](http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1754) [a couple times](http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1763) (at least on interacting with items in the WebContent folder, programmatically) and is worth reading. Ultimately, I try to put these sorts of public agnostic, common resources into my Domino */Data/domino/html/* path, so as to have it always public (that path is always publicly visible), and available to be set in a theme .

[Update]
See the link Per Henrik Lausten posted in the comments to the Q for details.
[/Update]