# sitemap not available for public acces

Tags: xpages

I made a website in xpages.
The default access is No access and read public documents.
For content I have to mark in the security settings "Available to public access users"
but
I've put my sitemap.xml under the webcontent folder.
How can I make this sitemap available to for example Google ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give public access to files under webcontent in lotus domino](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31520079/how-to-give-public-access-to-files-under-webcontent-in-lotus-domino)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file will be stored as a design Document in the database, accessible via NoteCollection. You'll probably need to do some trial and error to work out how to identify it, but you should then be able to set it as public access programmatically.

Alternatively, adding it as a File Resource will allow you to set it as public access via Domino Designer.

Another approach I've taken is to use a separate NSF for public access UI elements.

Comment: See this blog post for example code on how to change content in WebContent to be publicly accessible: http://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/public-access-to-e-g-an-angular-app-in-your-notes-database/